# Issue installing module via composer. - "package is fixed"

Tags: composer, 9

I've installed Drupal via Composer as well as 2 other modules and everything seemed ok. But now I tried installing [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) and get the following error message in console:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/nodeaccess ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/nodeaccess[1.0.0].
    - drupal/nodeaccess 1.0.0 requires drupal/core ^8 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.13] but the package is fixed to 9.1.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

and I don't know how to proceed. Any clues? T.I.A.

Comment: When asking Composer questions please always include the composer.json into your question body. Also please tell us what command you run to install the module. Many thanks.

Comment: The node access module doesn’t have a release for Drupal 9 yet

Comment: True, sorry. Nodeaccess shows as only for Drupal 8.*despite many other 8.* modules are also accepted by Drupal 9.* My fault.

Besides I've researched a lot about the 'webflo issues' and simply I could not understand the different suggestions about how to get rid of it. Still, sorry again for a inappropriate question, as it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, right answer was given by @Clive as Nodeacces module is not yet announced as ready for Drupal 9 (despite being worked out https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess/issues/3130778). So I believe (I'm not sure because I can't understand the composer error message) that's the reason for the error message I got.

Sorry for posting an inappropriate question, and thank you for the comments.